# How can improve this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I believe this is a SQL query running on Oracle:

```
SELECT ID, DEVICE_TYPE, S3_KEY, TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS CREATION_DAT
FROM KASE_DDL.ARCHIVED_LOG 
WHERE 
    CREATION_DATE >= TO_DATE('{DIST_YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS_UTC}', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND CREATION_DATE <= TO_DATE('{DIET_YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS_UTC}', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

It is running slow and I wonder how can I rewrite it to improve its efficiency. For example, can this query utilize indexing if there is an index built on CREATION_DATE? I remember reading books saying that if there is computation around a column, Oracle may not be able to use any index built on it. Is my query falling into this case? Any other suggestion? Thank you.

UPDATE:

In my problem, CREATION_DATE has an index built in. I am curious about whether this query enables the database to utilize the index or not.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(CREATION_DATE)`?

Comment: The query is not the problem obviously. Try adding an index on creation_date.

Comment: There's no function applied to the column `CREATION_DATE` in the `where` here, the function is on the other side. There's no reason for an index not to be taken if appropriate (you could really have given it a try too).

Comment: We can't provide reliable help unless we see the table and index definitions. Please paste them into your original question.

Comment: Just to double check... CREATION_DATE is a _date_ isn't it? If it is what is the cardinality of the column?

Comment: @ypercube What is this `{DIST_YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS_UTC}` and `{DIET_YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS_UTC}`. I have not seen this before. Specifically, what is dist, diet and why the curly braces?

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on `CREATION_DATE`.

I would also use the [`BETWEEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm) operator for the dates, but I like to read it that way.

Comment: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Comment: @ypercube Well, obviously look into how an operator works before using it. That's why I linked the docs.

Comment: I don't mind using `BETWEEN` when one is sure that the datatype is `DATE`. It's just easier to use open-closed intervals (with `>=`, `<`), as it works equally well with all datetime datatypes.

Comment: @ypercube - especially because timestamps are best conceptualized as the _first_ instance of 'something else'; ie an ending timestamp for status is better stored as the earliest timestamp for the _new_ status - the old status is 'current' so long as it's less than the 'new status'.

Answer (score 0):

For an additional performance gain you can try to use covering indexes.
In your case there is

```
create index ndxCovering on KASE_DDL.ARCHIVED_LOG(CREATION_DATE, ID, DEVICE_TYPE, S3_KEY);
```

It allows to read data only from index pages without seeking of data pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the probable effectiveness of the index by comparing the clustering_factor in the user_indexes table with the number of rows and the number of blocks for the table. The clustering factor will be between the number of blocks and the number of rows, which represent the theoretical minimum and maximum values respectively.

If the clustering factor is closer to the number of blocks (ie. it's relatively small) then the index will be more likely to be chosen and the selection of block from the table based on accessing the index will be require less work by the system.

It's always worth checking if you have any doubts about the performance improvements you're seeing when the index is used to access the table.